# How to get if/else statement to work inside function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use an if/else statement inside a function to make it so that orders over 50 have free shipping (s = 0).

I previously had shipping equal 15% of the cost of the order, which is now commented out. The function did work before I tried to add the if/else statement.

There are no error codes showing.

```
function estcost() {

  var p = document.getElementById("price").value; //gets price for plant as entered in box by user
  var p = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").value);
  var t = 0.086 * p; //calculates arizona sales tax
  //var s = 0.15*p;//calculates shipping cost based off of 15% of plant cost
  var s;
  if (p < 50) {
    s = 0.15 * p; //shipping for orders under $50
  } else {
    s = 0; //shipping for orders $50 and over
  }

  return s;
  var c = t + s + Number(p); //calculates final cost
  var f = '$' + c.toFixed(2); //rounds cost to 2 decimal places

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = f; //allows me to call f in html
}
```

Comment: You've `return s` before you do `innerHTML` regardless of `if....else`! i.e your last 3 statements inside function will never get executed.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of issues:

1. You declare `p` twice. While this isn't completetly wrong, there is no need to do it. Remove the first `var p = document....`
2. You `return s` before you display your results. Using `return` will stop the function from running, thus making all the code below it not run. Either remove this (if your not doing anything with it) or move it to the bottom of your function.
3. Although it isn't a necessary change, you can instead declare `var s` to be `var s = 0` and only change it if `p < 50`, allowing you to remove the `else`.

See working example below:

```js
function estcost() {
  var p = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").value);
  var t = 0.086 * p; //calculates arizona sales tax
 
  var s = 0;
  if (p < 50) {
    s = 0.15 * p; //shipping for orders under $50
  }
  var c = t + s + Number(p); //calculates final cost
  var f = '$' + c.toFixed(2); //rounds cost to 2 decimal places
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = f; //allows me to call f in html
  
  return s; // move to bottom
}
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="price" id="price" />
<p>Result: <span id="result"></span></p>
<button onclick="estcost()">Estimate Cost</button>
```

Comment: Good explanation for him! Actually, if you use `let` instead of `var` on a double declaration you will fall on error: _SyntaxError: redeclaration of let..._ SO it is good for him to know that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `return` statement is too soon in your function - it stops the rest of the function from executing. Placing the `return` statement at the bottom of the function should fix this problem:

```
function estcost() {
  var p = document.getElementById("price").value; //gets price for plant as entered in box by user
  var p = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").value);
  var t = 0.086 * p; //calculates arizona sales tax
  //var s = 0.15*p;//calculates shipping cost based off of 15% of plant cost
  var s;
  if (p < 50) {
    s = 0.15 * p; //shipping for orders under $50
  } else {
    s = 0; //shipping for orders $50 and over
  }
  var c = t + s + Number(p); //calculates final cost
  var f = '$' + c.toFixed(2); //rounds cost to 2 decimal places
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = f; //allows me to call f in html
  return s;
}
```